# Pull All Column Names from SQLEXPRESS and insert into PHP Array

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to get a list of all the columns available in a SQLEXPRESS table.  This is the relevant code below:

```
$getColumns = sqlsrv_query($conn, $columnQuery);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getColumns)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Here are the results from that code:
GUIDFromServerRecTypeProfileNameActionTimeOccurredUserNameUserLDAPNameTSStationTSRemoteAddrUserSIDIPv4FromIPv6FromisDirectorywasBlockedACEtypeFullFilePathShareNameFileNameOnlyNewPathNameSIDOfNewOwnerACLObjectLDAPNameACLObjectDomainACLObjectNameACLMaskACLFlagsACLObjectType

It is the column names I need, but they are all in a single string rather than broken up 1 column per entry in the array the way I need it.  I figured this much out by reseaching on this site, but no one mentioned in those other questions that this was a problem.

Comment: If using a browser `echo $row[0] . '<br />';` if using CLI `echo $row[0] . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Thank you for at least pointing me in the right direction here.  The first option puts each column name on a separate line and the second one puts a space between each object which gets me closer to where I need to be.  I am still learning so I need to look into splitting it on a space and pushing that into an array so I can do things like foreach.  Thank you.

Comment: while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getColumns)) {
  $tempColumns = ($row[0] . PHP_EOL);
  $selectColumns = explode(" ", $tempColumns);
  echo $selectColumns[0];
 }